# Unable to read the custom xsd namespace present in the SOAP Request & Response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xsd, xml-parsing

I am trying to read the element nodes of the SOAP XML Request & Response using the below piece of Java code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        System.out.println("Node Name: " + node.getNodeName() + ", Node Text: " + node.getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

Let say the SOAP XML Request is as below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:TestRequest xmlns:ns1="urn:wu:eh:dis:test:xsd:TestRequest-v1.0.0" xmlns:ns2="urn:wu:eh:dis:test:xsd:TestRequest" xmlns:ns3="urn:wu:eh:dis:test:xsd:TestSystem" xmlns:xyz1="urn:wu:eh:dis:test:xsd:TestSystem">
         <ns2:TestRequest>
            <ns3:TestSystem>
               <ns3:UserName>test</ns3:UserName>
               <ns3:Password>test</ns3:Password>
            </ns3:TestSystem>
         </ns2:TestRequest>
         <xyz1:TestRequest>
            <xyz1:TestSystem>
               <xyz1:UserName>test</xyz1:UserName>
               <xyz1:Password>test</xyz1:Password>
            </xyz1:TestSystem>
         </xyz1:TestRequest>
      </ns1:TestRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In the above SOAP XML Request, I am able to read the element nodes of TestSystem schema with the namespace ns2 whereas the TestSystem schema with namespace xyz1 is not readable. Could anyone please help me the correction/problem in the Java code?

Answer (score 1):

The construction of your SOAP xml is wrong, that is why it is not gettting parsed properly. Some of the end tags are not matching the start tags:

```
<xyz1:UserName>test</ns3:UserName>
<xyz1:Password>test</ns3:Password>
```

Comment: Sorry to have included the wrong end tags. I have updated the sample SOAP XML Request.

Comment: I am able to read from the corrected SOAP xml you provided for both ns2 and xyz1, although I had to use node.getTextContent() to read the node content